# Eclipse java automatic method finder

Tags: java, methods

Why is that when I tried to type within my java program on eclipse method won't show up every time I added a dot after the object or just plane method that extends let's say Activity.

Answer (score 3):

You have to push <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>space</kbd> to view the methods and/or variables associated with the particular object. Using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>space</kbd> is what activates the code completion. Sometimes Java will do it automatically, other times it won't. When it doesn't do it on it's own, just use the method I described here.